# iptables FORWARD chain rule without destination address specified

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

I was given this set of iptables rule that supposedly works.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn --dport 5213 -m limit --limit 120/m --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn --dport 5213 -j DROP
```

I understand the part about limiting the number of TCP-SYNs that are accepted. What I'm confused about is how the `FORWARD` chain was used.

I usually see rules under the `FORWARD` chain specifying the source/destination IP address, but the rules above only specified the destination port.

Does this mean that the destination is still the system that received this message? If so, what would be the difference if I used the `INPUT` chain instead?

Comment: `FORWARD` is for packets passing through your box.  `INPUT` is only for packets destined for that box.

Comment: I know that part, but where would it be forwarded to if it didn't specify the destination IP address?

Comment: These rules aren't changing the routing.  The normal `ip route` rules should apply.  Since it is a `FORWARD` rule it would rate limit this port for any destinations or origins.

Answer (score 1):

As @chicks says in the comments, default routing rules apply.  Once the packet exits a `FORWARD` chain as `ACCEPT`ed, it will leave the system according to the routing table.